# IQueryable for 1 to N tables to select all the data (c#)

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I am beginner of C#, and I am writing the code for "search" function now. I have linked table which is 1 to N like example below. And, I like to find out the data for table A which matches e.g. table B, "KeyB002". (Answer is KeyA001 & KeyA003). 
I have been using IQueryable, and is this okay with this syntax? Or, this won't work? I am wondering SingleOrDefault or FirstOrDefault will pick up only the first key which is attached with tableA, and don't go through (search) from all the attached keys and find out the data in tableA....

Thank you very much.

(Current Syntax) FYI - searchtableB_ID from screen...

```
var IqueryableData = from m in db.tableA.Include(p => p.tableB) select m; 
IqueryableData = IqueryableData.Where(s => s.tableB.SingleOrDefault().tableB_Key == searchtableB_ID);
```

table A & table B:
KeyA001 - KeyB001
KeyA001 - KeyB002
KeyA001 - KeyB005
KeyA001 - KeyB007

KeyA002 - KeyB003
KeyA002 - KeyB005
KeyA002 - KeyB008

KeyA003 - KeyB001
KeyA003 - KeyB002
KeyA003 - KeyB006
KeyA003 - KeyB009

Comment: The FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefault expression within the WHERE query won't prevent more than one record from being returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could just:

```
var queryableData = db.tableB.Include(p => p.tableA).Where(q=> q.tableB_key == searchtableB_ID).First(m => m.tableA);
```

Notice the reversed Include (p => p.tableB) instead of (p => p.tableA)